# How to wrap ng-change in custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive called `input-text`, that basically wraps an input control.

The value given to `input-text` attribute is passed to `ng-model` and works just fine. Now I also want to pass a function that is invoked on any change of the model by passing this to an attribute called `input-change`.

```
angular.module('test').directive('inputText', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {
      inputText : '='
    },
    template : '<input ng-model="inputText" />',
    link : function(scope, element, attr) {
      var model = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');
      model.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
        scope.$parent.$eval(attr.inputChange);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/qC7FlxVNKH4SrAhLoJy4 for more details.

The function passed to the directive gets called every time I type in the control but the value I get logged in the console is not the current `$viewValue` from the control (but the previous one).

I also tried a different approach by passing the string given to `input-change` to `ng-change` on the input control like so:

```
angular.module('test').directive('inputText', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {
      inputText : '=',
      inputChange : '&'
    },
    template : '<input ng-model="inputText" ng-change="inputChange()" />',
  }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SutAFnCgo10QNmvBFsDs

But the output is the same as in the example above.

Can someone please explain this behavior or tell what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around this is to explicitly expose the input value on its `input-change` binding. To do that you can use this template:

```
<input ng-model="inputText" ng-change="inputChange({value: inputText})" />
```

And then use that `value` variable from the inner scope rather than the `test.model.name` variable from the outer scope: `input-change="test.callback(value)"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/SNatIAkPIHFSMooMWWFS?p=preview

---

A second option is to watch for the changes with `scope.$watch` and only trigger your function when that is triggered:

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.$watch('inputText', function(n) {
    scope.inputChange();
  });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vrwe3SC3ejMG4aFIwBTU?p=preview

Comment: I also tried your first suggestion before, but this came up to be quite inflexible, since I might want to put a variable amount of parameters to the function. The second is quite obvious and works well, thanks. Still, I would like to know, why the behavior is strange in my explained cases.

Comment: @M.Redemske with option 1 nothing prevents you to use other variables. It jsut add `value` as locals. For instance you can write `test.callback(model1, value, model2)` with model1 and model2 that come from the upper scope and `value` which is provided by the directive. As to why you had the issue, I also personally got it and never really knew if that was a bug in Angular itself or something not clear with ng-change.